# How to build queries with comparison operators using mongodb official driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

I need to build a query using comparison operators, equivalent of `db.inventory.find( { qty: { $gt: 20 }` using the [official driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a server is something like:

```
client, err := mongo.NewClient("mongodb://foo:bar@localhost:27017")
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
err = client.Connect(context.TODO())
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
```

Then obtain the `inventory` [`mongo.Collection`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection) like:

```
coll := client.Database("baz").Collection("inventory")
```

Then you can execute your query using [`Collection.Find()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.Find) like:

```
ctx := context.Background()

cursor, err := coll.Find(ctx,
    bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("qty",
            bson.EC.Int32("$gt", 20),
        ),
    ),
)

defer cursor.Close(ctx) // Make sure you close the cursor!
```

Reading the results using the [`mongo.Cursor`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Cursor):

```
doc := bson.NewDocument()
for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    doc.Reset()
    if err := cursor.Decode(doc); err != nil {
        // Handle error
        log.Printf("cursor.Decode failed: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Do something with doc:
    log.Printf("Result: %v", doc)    
}

if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("cursor.Err: %v", err)
}
```

Note: I used a single [`bson.Document`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Document) value to read all documents, and used its [`Document.Reset()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Document.Reset) in the beginning of each iteration to clear it and "prepare" it to read a new document into it. If you want to store the documents (e.g. in a slice), then you can obviously not do this. In that case just create a new doc in each iteration like `doc := bson.NewDocument()`.